# How to randomize booleans in bulk

Tags: swift, random

I want to randomize 10,000 booleans in pure swift and get the sum of all those that are true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sum can be conveniently computed with the `reduce()` function:

```
/// Return the result of repeatedly calling `combine` with an
/// accumulated value initialized to `initial` and each element of
/// `sequence`, in turn.
func reduce<S : SequenceType, U>(sequence: S, initial: U, combine: (U, S.Generator.Element) -> U) -> U
```

If you are only interested in the sum:

```
let sum = reduce(0 ..< 10000, 0) { (sum, _) in sum + Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) }
```

If you need the Bool array and the sum:

```
let bools = map (0 ..< 10000) { _ in arc4random_uniform(2) == 1 }
let sum = reduce(bools, 0) { $0 + Int($1) }
```

*Update:* As Zaph suggested below, one should utilize all 32 bits from
the `arc4random...` functions to reduce the number of function calls. This would be

```
let numberOfInt32 = 10000 / 32
let remainingBits = 10000 % 32

let sum = reduce(0 ..< numberOfInt32, 0) { (sum, _) in sum + NumberOfSetBits(arc4random()) }
    + NumberOfSetBits(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(1 << remainingBits)))
```

where `NumberOfSetBits()` counts the number of set bits and is a
translation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/1187415 to Swift:

```
func NumberOfSetBits(var i : UInt32) -> Int {
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555)
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333)
    return Int((((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) &* 0x01010101) >> 24)
}
```

(See also [Rikkle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214433/1187415)
which was posted in the mean time ...)

Comment: There remains one issue, 10,000 calls to arc4random_uniform in a short time may well overwhelm the capabilities to produce cryptographically random numbers. Just using arc4random() and using all 32-bits would help avoid this potential problem by reducing the calls by a factor of 32.

Comment: @Zaph: thanks for the feedback, I have tried to implement your suggestion. For the sum of 10.000 random bits, it reduces the time from 8ms to approx 0.3ms on my computer. Using arc4random_buf as Rikkle suggested in his answer might even be faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to save your booleand

```
var sum = 0
for i in 1...10000{
   if(arc4random_uniform(2) == 1)
      sum++
}
```

If you do want to save them

```
var sum = 0
var boolArrays = []
for i in 1...10000{
   if(arc4random_uniform(2) == 1){
      sum++
      boolArray.addObject(true)
   }
   else{
       boolArray.addObject(false)
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `random()` it is not random, instead use `arc4random()` or in this case `arc4random_uniform(2)`. Further, `random()` without a seed will repeat each tie the program is run.

Comment: forgot to remove it, arc4random)uniform(n) will create random number in range of 0 to n-1. Thanks again

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: it must be: "for i in 1...10000" ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `arc4random_buf` on a 10,000/8 number of bytes, then applying the sideways addition (or "Hamming Weight") to sum up all the bits in that series of bytes, one int (32 bits) at a time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/1401029 for good pseudo code of the Hamming Weight.

This should be significantly faster and cleaner than any looping construct that includes a random function inside it.

Comment: After reading your answer I also assumed that calling arc4random_buf() once (on a buffer of size 10,000/8) is faster than calling arc4random() 10,000/32 times. I made a simple benchmark now and interestingly, it turned out that there is almost no difference in the timing.

Comment: Interesting! So the buffer version mosty loops throught the int32 version. Still though, both are probably much faster than doing arc4random_uniform() to get a 0/1 value on each bit.

Comment: Oh I just saw your comment above that drops the time by 25x between the bit and the word. Good :)

Comment: Actually that comparison was done in Debug mode. In Release mode and with Swift 1.2 the difference is 24ms vs 0.8 ms for 1,000,000 bits.

Comment: And I do hope that you believe me that I did not copy your ideas. I started working on the improved version after receiving Zaph's comment and found the same NumberOfSetBits() function. I saw (and upvoted) your answer only when my improved code was ready to be posted.

Comment: No worries. I was surprised everyone was suggesting getting a horribly inefficient random bit every time.

Answer (score 1):

> arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number
>   less than upper_bound.

```
var countTrue : Int = 0
var countFalse : Int = 0
for i in 1 ... 10000 {
    if (arc4random_uniform(2) == 1) {
         countTrue++
    } else {
         countFalse++
    }
}

NSLog("count true: \(countTrue), count false: \(countFalse)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the actual Booleans, the sum has a binomial distribution with `N=10000` and `p=1/2`.  For that large an N, it's pretty much indistinguishable from a Gaussian with a mean of `N*p` and a variance of `N*p*(1-p)` (which corresponds to a standard deviation of 50), rounded to the nearest integer.  You can generate standard normals using the Box-Muller method, and scale as follows:

```
import Cocoa

let uniform_denom = UInt32(RAND_MAX) + 1

func u0_1() -> Double {
  var num = arc4random_uniform(uniform_denom)
  return Double(num) / Double(uniform_denom)
}

func gaussian() -> (Double, Double) {
  var d = sqrt(-2.0 * log(u0_1()))
  var theta = 2.0 * M_PI * u0_1()
  return (d * cos(theta), d * sin(theta))  // 2-tuple of std normals
}

var sum = 5000 + Int(round(50.0 * gaussian().0))  // scale to mean = 5000, std-dev = 50
```